# Concatenate strings into an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, highcharts, concatenation

I have these array in javascript that is going to be the input data for a graph using highcharts

data = [**20**, 29, 25, 30, 21, 17, 20, **19**, 18];

and what I need is to be able to concatenate certain strings to get in the end these

data = [**{ color: '#55B647', y: 20 }**, 29, 25, 30, 21, 17, 20, **{ color: '#F15B49', y: 19 }**, 18];

I was trying to acces the array and assing the new value like these

data[0]= "{ color: '#55B647', y:" + data[0] + "}";

But is not working, how can I do it? What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Depends on the requirements of Highcharts. Is it expecting a JSON string or an object literal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be right:

```
data[0] = { color: '#55B647', y: data[0] };
```

Rememeber that an object in JS is declared like:

```
var object = { key1: value1, key2: value2};
```

Comment: The issue was your use of strings. This is the correct answer.